# Dynamically Exclude Content In PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I am making a PHP-based application which will fetch content from a site using the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

I want to exclude some text between two HTML tags from the content dynamically.

If the source code of the content is:

```
Some description or content ETC ABC <span class="s"> May 3  2009 <b> ABC Some Text </b> Some photo or video...
```

I want to remove all the text wrapped by `<span class="s">` to the first `<b>` HTML tag, so the output will be:

```
Some description or content ETC ABC <span class="s"><b> ABC Some Text </b> Some photo or video...
```

This should done using a `foreach` loop and, the idea is, to get all the filtered text in a variable like `$ftext` and then have to apply some simple PHP like:

```
foreach($html->find('how_to_tell_those_filtered_text_here') as $ftext)
$result = str_replace($ftext, '', $result);
$result = str_get_html($result);
```

So, what should be the solution, any idea?

Comment: Waht have you tried yourself as a possible solution?

Comment: Please read through the [editing FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to format your questions.

Answer (score 0):

better if you use readability by Arc90 HTML content extractor

Comment: ah! actually ama beginner so would u refer me any article or if possible any example? Thanks