# Getting Specific Data in PHP

Tags: php, variables

What is the way to get specific data using PHP. In this case i want to get some text which is wrapped by `<span class="s">` to the first `<b>` HTML tag.
Assuming a HTML source code is:

```
Once there was a king <span class="s"> May 3  2009 <b> ABC Some Text </b> Some photo or video</span> but they have...
```

So, here i want to get those filtered data in a variable like: `$fdata = "May 3 2009";`
Because, `May 3  2009` is wrapped by `<span class="s">` to the first `<b>` HTML tag.

I will use it in SIMPLE PHP HTML DOM PARSING. So, any idea or example to filter those text and get it in a variable? Any idea will be a great help. 
*If you found a duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177740/dynamically-exclude-content-in-php-simple-html-dom-parser), its not that its more specified.

Comment: Are you asking how to use simple html dom parser to grab the elements?

Comment: actually i can't understand how to filter those text and get in a variable, if its possible then i will able to play it with simple html dom parser.

Answer (score 2):

Use Simple HTML DOM
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Or http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Or you can use any other library also.

Comment: yeah thanks, but i know that. What i can't understand is how to get those text which wrapped by `<span class="s">` to the first `<b>` HTML tag, and declare that in a variable, if u know n if possible please give me an example.

Comment: Hmm, if you don't want to figure out the code maybe check out: http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/ seems you could chain it like a jQuery selector if you are more comfortable with that.

Comment: is that possible to get that data by `preg_replace`, if so n if possible for you please show me a example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using simple html dom parser you'd grab the elements you're targeting like this:

```
$ret = $html->find('span class="s"');
```

This is just a basic sample, but it should get you going in the right direction.

if you need to find a very specific instance, you can use something such as:

```
$ret = $html->find("#div1", 0)->children(1)->children(1)->children(2)->id;
```

Comment: actually i wanna get some filtered text in a variable, so we can compare it as getting a youtube video id from a url in a variable.

Comment: using my first example, it should return `May 3  2009 <b> ABC Some Text </b> Some photo or video`. Then you could trim everything after `May 3 2009`. You'll probably have to come up with some RegEx to handle this since the length of the month and day will probably vary.

Comment: thanks, i am trying with this but dont works: `foreach($result->find('span class="s"') as $ftext)
$new_des = implode(' ', array_slice(str_word_count($ftext, 1),0,4));
$result = str_replace($new_des, '', $result);
$result = str_get_html($result);` so it can delete first 4 word of `span class="s"`, how to to make it work?